# Google Plus fixed Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have seen that Google+ has this cool layout, where the only thing that can be scrolled is in the middle of the page with its content, but the actual scroller is fixed to the right side of the window.. I have searched a lot to find maybe a way to do this myself, but with no luck.. :) does anybody know how this is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use `position: fixed` to make the edge elements stay in place.

Like, if you have:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 10p;">
  This will always be 10px from the top left of your window, even when you scroll
</div>
```

Comment: I know about the fixed property, but it didn't seem to that google where using 'fixed'..

Comment: I checked, they are. What makes you think they don't?

Comment: Actually I don't know.. :) I just thought they have found other ways to do it. Thank you then!

Answer (score 0):

the gray boarder-elements are fixed with `position: absolute;` and the postition is set with `top: ...px; left: ...px; right: ...px; or bottom: ...px;` . So your declare some elements with a width and a height and that the position of them.

On example from the code: (its the left gray area)

```
.Zaa, .MHPMSc {
    bottom: -74px;
    outline: medium none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

greetings!

Comment: `position: absolute` removes the element from normal document flow but they will not stick to the viewport.

Comment: yes. But the question was how it works in google plus ;) you need a long content area to scroll. and with the positioning of top and bottom you support different screen resolutions.